# Is it possible to turn my Mac Pro into an FTP server without using any third party FTP clients like Filezilla or VSFTPD?

Tags: linux, ftp, homebrew, home-server, vsftpd

I want to turn a Mac Pro Tower into an FTP server that exchanges files locally between my MacBooks and Homebrewed PS3 and Xbox 360.

I don’t want to install any third party FTP clients and am wondering if linux comes with by default a way to turn your computer into an FTP server in the kernel.

Although I could just copy the files on all of my systems, I'm curious and want to try this.

Answer (score 3):

OSX has a standard option to share via ftp:

1. Choose `System Preferences` from the Apple icon
2. Click `Sharing`
3. Select the `File Sharing` box and click `Options`
4. Click `Share Files and Folders Using FTP`